# Using SFML Network with SDL2

Tags: c++, c, tcp, sdl, sfml

I have a program using SDL2, SDL2_ttf, SDL2_image and SDL2_mixer! 
I thought about using SDL_net for networking but i saw the networking module of SFML and the packet system for TCP and i would like to use **ONLY** the Network module of SFML from the SFML library.

Is that possible?

Is there a Packet system for SDL_net (the official hasn't got one)?

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't work. As for SDL_net - I don't get your question. What does "packet system" means to you? After all networking is all about exchanging packets, so surely it could send packets. You also might want to consider [enet](http://enet.bespin.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is that possible?

Yes!

Basically, when [setting up your project](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/#getting-started) you need to link against `sfml-system` and `sfml-network` (and SDL libs of course).

You can then [communicate with sockets](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/network-socket.php) or [use packets](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/network-packet.php) and the [other features provided by SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/group__network.php).

The same applies for the [audio module](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/#audio-module), too.

Comment: [you already know it does.](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=15566.msg110921#msg110921)